# Sort an ArrayList of integer arrays

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

how can i sort an ArrayList of integer array based on the last integer in the integer array?

```
ArrayList<int[]> paths = new ArrayList<int[]>();
paths.add(new int[]{0,0,0,0,4});
paths.add(new int[]{0,0,0,0,2});
paths.add(new int[]{0,0,0,0,1});
paths.add(new int[]{0,0,0,0,3});
```

the resulting ArrayList would contain: [0,0,0,1] [0,0,0,2]  [0,0,0,3]  [0,0,0,4]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement a `Comparator` and use `Collections.sort`. Or do both at once:

```
Collections.sort(paths, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return (Integer)(a[a.length-1]).compareTo(b[b.length-1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm getting this:
Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int

Comment: Try either `return a[a.length-1] -b[b.length-1];` or `return Integer.valueOf(a[a.length-1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b[b.length-1]));`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version with a comparator that doesn't do autoboxing or casting:

```
public class Sorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> paths = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        paths.add(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4 });
        paths.add(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 });
        paths.add(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 });
        paths.add(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 3 });
        Collections.sort(paths, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            private static final int INDEX = 4;
            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1[INDEX], o2[INDEX]);
            }
        });
        for (int[] is : paths) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(is));
        }
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```

Comment: You save my day! Works perfectly. Same case scenario as mine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using Java-8

```java
paths.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[a.length - 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [java.util.Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)... all you need to do is write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares two of your Arrays and the rest is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code it should be `paths.add(...)` not `path.add(...)`

If you don't want to implement `Comparator` you could always write a method yourself. If efficiency isn't important this could work (bubble sort - obviously it could be much better using a better sorting algorithm):

```
public ArrayList<int[]> sort() {
    ArrayList<int[]> sortedArray = this;
    boolean switched = true;
    while(switched) {
        switched = false;
        for(int i=0; i<sortedArray.size()-1; i++)
            int[] a = sortedArray.get(i);
            int[] b = sortedArray.get(i+1);
            if(a[a.length]>b[b.length]) {
                sortedArray.set(i, b);
                sortedArray.set(i+1, a);
                switched = true;
            }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

This goes through the ArrayList and checks if the last element of each pair of consecutive arrays is in the right order. If so, it checks the next pair; if not, it switches the two arrays int the ArrayList. It continues going through the ArrayList until it doesn't have to do anymore switches; at this point the ArrayList is sorted.

Comment: `ArrayList<int[]> sortedArray = this` -- what do you expect that to do?

Comment: Are you suggesting I make it a void method?